# Alarm manager when the user change the date from the device

Tags: android

My main objective is to send a user one notification after 24 hours the problem comes when the user change date from the device to the past.

My code only work for the future , can someone explain to me how to fix it ?

```
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, firstTime, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP to fire an alarm **in 24 hours** instead of **at X time tomorrow**.

*ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP—Wakes up the device and fires the pending intent after the specified length of time has elapsed since device boot.*

Source : Android developer

This example fires an alarm every 30 minutes and is not sensitive to clock changes :

```
    alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,

         AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HALF_HOUR,

   AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HALF_HOUR, 

alarmIntent);
```

Comment: i need to have a notification first on specific time and than after 24 hours 
Like you have said   :Length of time has elapsed since device boot.